# Easily manage user input forms in a PHP Web Application

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services, web

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I'm writing a simple web application in plain HTML+PHP. I'm not using any framework, content manager or anything.

The entry page has a few checkboxes, two textboxes and a series of dropdown menus. Then once everything is selected, the user clicks a "Search" button and then it runs some PHP code and returns an output.

The problem is with the dropdown menus. The code is the following :

```
<form action=$script method=\"get\" name=\"org\">
<select name=\"org\" onChange=\"Javascript:document.org.submit();\">
<option value=\"0\">(Default All)</option>
<option value=\"1\">Cars</option>
<option value=\"2\">Parts</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Then every time the user selects an option, the webpage is reloaded and a GET variable is set. Now I have two problems :

1.- I would like that the option selected in the dropdown menu is shown the first, so the user knows what he has clicked. The only way to do that is put a php switch at the beginning of the form and echo the new dropdown menu depending on the get variable that was set in the previous submitform.

2.- I have to create a nightmarish spaguetti code in index.php that handles if the user has clicked on the search button or not, etc.

Is there anyway to handle that in a more professional and easy way ? Wether it would be javascripts, frameworks or PHP modules. Or a tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. You have to compare all options values with sent $_GET, if true - add `selected` attribute

Answer (score 0):

1.) add selected to the selected option

```
<option value=\"1\" selected>Cars</option>
```

2.) check if get parameters are set or not (if they are set, the form has been submitted)

Comment: What I want to avoid is to check the get parameters every time. I'm sure there's an easy way to do that.